# how do i make a grading system using cases?

Tags: postgresql

pretty sure this is a pretty simple issue:

I need to create an exam results table for a student, but it needs to meet the conditions of If the student is awarded a grade of 70% or more then the result is to be shown as 'Distinction', a grade of at least 50% but less than 70% is to be shown as 'Pass' and grades below 50% are to be shown as 'Fail'. If the student has not taken the examination then the result is shown as 'Not taken'.

I'm having issues with my code which i can't seem to get right:

```
CREATE VIEW results_table
AS SELECT entry.excode, sname, student.sno, entry.egrade, result AS entry 
FROM student
JOIN entry
ON student.sno = entry.sno
GROUP BY entry.excode,  sname, student.sno, entry.egrade, result

SELECT result
    CASE result
        WHEN entry.egrade >= 70 THEN 'Distinction'
        WHEN entry.egrade >= 50 THEN 'Pass'
        WHEN entry.egrade < 50 THEN 'Fail'
        WHEN entry.egrade = NULL THEN 'Not Taken'

    END;


ORDER BY entry.excode,sname
```

could somebody please tell me where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of SQL `CASE` statement, [as documented for PostgreSQL here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html):

- `CASE WHEN condition THEN result ELSE default END`
- `CASE expression WHEN value THEN result ELSE default END`

The first form tests a series of (unrelated) conditions, and returns the result for the first one which is true, or the `ELSE` if none are. The second form is a short-hand for testing multiple conditions against a single value; `CASE x WHEN y THEN 'y' WHEN z THEN 'z' END` is short-hand for `CASE WHEN x = y THEN 'y' WHEN x = z THEN 'z' END`.

In your code, you're muddling the two syntaxes; you can't use the short-hand because you're doing something more complex than `=` in the conditions, so you need to leave out the word `result`:

```
CASE
    WHEN entry.egrade >= 70 THEN 'Distinction'
    WHEN entry.egrade >= 50 THEN 'Pass'
    WHEN entry.egrade < 50 THEN 'Fail'
    WHEN entry.egrade IS NULL THEN 'Not Taken'
END
```

(**Note:** I've also changed `= NULL` to `IS NULL`, since no value is ever "equal to" `NULL`, because it means "we don't know what the value is equal to".)

You then need to put that into a `SELECT` query in the same place you'd select a normal column.

So starting from this simple query...

```
SELECT
    entry.egrade as result
FROM
    entry;
```

...you can put your `CASE` statement in like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN entry.egrade >= 70 THEN 'Distinction'
        WHEN entry.egrade >= 50 THEN 'Pass'
        WHEN entry.egrade < 50 THEN 'Fail'
        WHEN entry.egrade IS NULL THEN 'Not Taken'
    END as result
FROM
    entry;
```

Comment: @ayoolaadedeji Glad to have helped. I've reverted your edit to the question, because the design of this site is that future visitors can see your original problem and see whether it matches theirs, then look down at the answers if so. Your edit obscured the original problem, so broke this design.